# Python execute script using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

How can I write x in search box? when I try to get string in execute script , it's get a error

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    x = '123321'
    #driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value='abcde'")
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value=x")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Should be*

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value =" + x)
```

*Also remove the trailing semicolon **`;`** from the following statement*

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

*Full code example*

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
x = '123321'

driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value =" + x)
```